# Interpolating blacked out ROI in an image with python

Tags: python, image-processing, interpolation

I have been browsing the internet and stack overflow in order to find a solution to my problem, but to no avail.
So here is my problem:

**Problem**

I have a series of images with specific ROIs, where I detect a signal change. In order to extract the signal I need subtract the background of the image from the actual signal. Unfortunately I can't just subtract the images, as this doesn't delete the background noise sufficiently.

**Solution Idea**

What I want to do is to cut out (black out) my ROIs and then do an interpolation across the entire "reduced" image. Then I want to fill in the blacked out ROIs again via interpolation. This way I can get an idea of what the background below my signal is actually doing. I have been playing around with *griddata*, *RectBivariateSpline*, but I haven't found a way that works.

So far I have been doing this in MATLAB with the function *scatteredInterpolant*, but I would like to do it in python.
Below an image series, that describes the concept. One can see the third image being slightly blurry in the before blacked out ROIs.

[Imageprocessing concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okKeq.png)

So, does python provide a solution or way, which is similar to MATLABs *scatteredInterpolant* or how could I best tackle this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at *"inpainting"*? https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html